Safe Transaction Builder not accepting tuple parameter
I'm trying to use the Safe Transaction Builder to do a facet upgrade on an ERC2535 Diamond. The contract is not verified but I successfully pasted the abi. The problem happens when I try to enter the parameter for _diamondCut is:
_diamondCut(tuple(address,uint8,bytes4[][])

I have tried several different syntaxes for this and I always get "format error. details: TypeError: n.map is not a function" error in the UI.
Here is the closet I can get this syntax:
["0x614d6909EF7F0450083D2067D0861321058e8847","0",[""]]

What am I missing? Is there a special way to format tuples in the builder?

This seems to be a problem linked to Safe{Wallet}. I suggest you visit help.safe.global and contact the dedicated support team, by clicking on the message icon at the bottom right of the page and explain the problem to them.
This stack exchange tag (safe-core) is more intended to be used for developers having trouble building on top of Safe{Core}.
Hope it helps! Best, Louis
